# How to grab the last 12 months from cygwin "date" and use the months for git sync

Tags: git, date, cygwin, git-checkout

I'm trying to compare the trees of a repo as they were at the end of the month for the past 12 months, to see what changed.  I am a newb - so far my code basically looks like this:

`for month in Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep`

`git checkout $(git rev-list --before "$month 1 2011" -n 1 HEAD)`

I'd like to make this work for the last 12 months, going back to the previous year.  I want it to by dynamic - how do I make a loop that iterates over the last 12 months, ending on the current month?  I want the month value to be a variable I can use both in `for "..."` and in my `git checkout ...` line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

```
for i in {1..12}; do
    git checkout $(git rev-list --before "$(date -d "$(date -d +%Y-%m-15) -$i months" +%Y-%m)-01" -n 1 HEAD)
    ...
done
```

Comment: fatal: ambiguous argument 'months': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

Comment: Which command is giving the fatal error?  The git command should never have seen the word "months", as that was a parameter to `date`.

Comment: Are you sure you entered that command exactly as I wrote it? There are a number of potential quoting issues if you aren't careful.

Comment: Missed a parenthesis!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Almost!  One issue:  it seems that the is an error for February...  As a test I wrote `mkir "$(date -d "$i months ago" +%Y-%m)-01"` just to see if I'd get 12 months worth of directories.  Instead of making `2011-02-01` it tries to make `2011-03-01` twice.  Ideas?!